# iOS password autofill for multiple subdomains with same credentials

Tags: ios, xcode

i am trying to make ios password autofill work. I have several subdomains with same credentials for each eg. `example1.domain1.com`, `example2.domain1.com`, `example3.domain1.com`. Is it possible to just put `apple-app-site-association` file to top level domain `domain1.com` and use wildcard in xcode project like `webcredentials:*.domain1.com` ? Or is it necessary to put ASSA file to each subdomain ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

need add to each domain

> If your site uses different subdomains (such as developerinsider.co, developerinsider.in, and tech.developerinsider.co) each requires its own entry in the Associated Domains, and each must serve its own apple-app-site-association file